# mongo db - get table records with count of another collection

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections, category and product. 
Each product has a category_id. i want to list the category names with product count... 
I have done this with 1 looping and 2 queries. but i want make this as a single query.
How to generate that in mongo DB?

```
public function GetCategories(){

    $data = array();

    $this->cimongo->where(array('status'=>'1'));
    $query = $this->cimongo->get('category');
    foreach($query->result_array() as $category){ 
        $data[] = array(
            'keyword'       => $category['keyword'], 
            'name'          => $category['name'],
            'total'         => $this->GetTotalWordsByCategoryId($category['_id'])
        );
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: You can't query two collections with one query.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing that can make this as a single query. Mongodb does not have joins, so and because of this if you want to make it as one query you have to store information about second collection in the first.

Comment: no, mapreduce also operates on the collection level. All joins should be done on the application layer.